# Replace a string in string that is in a List<string>

Tags: c#, regex, linq, replace

I need help with the following issue

I have the string:

```
string myString = "This is not a drill"
```

and a list of strings:

```
List<string> lst = {"January", "james", "not"}
```

I want to find if any of the items in the list is in the string and replace it with $$string$$

wanted output:

"This is $$not$$ a drill"

Thanks

**Update**

I tried using the

```
termsList.Any(sentence.SentenceContent.Contains)
```

to find if it is contained in the string
and then

```
Regex.Replace(input, textToFind, replace);
```

but it didnt work

Comment: dare I ask... what have you tried?

Comment: @Bergkamp, do not post additional details in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: Have you even seacrh and didn't find string.Contains() method???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Iterate over all strings inside List and then check if `myString` contains that or not. If yes, then replace it.

```
foreach (string item in lst)
{
    if (myString.Contains(item))
    {
        myString = myString.Replace(item, string.Format("$${0}$$", item));
    }
}
```

---

Also you can do same with LINQ:

```
lst.Where(item=> myString.Contains(item)).ToList()
   .ForEach(item => myString = myString.Replace(item, string.Format("$${0}$$", item)));
```

---

You can also split string by spaces, and check if they exist in List or not:

```
 myString.Split(' ').ToList()
         .Where(x => lst.Contains(x)).ToList()
         .ForEach(item => myString = myString.Replace(item, string.Format("$${0}$$", item)));
```

---

**Case insensivity**:

Change `Contains(x)` to `Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

For example the third method:

```
 myString.Split(' ').ToList()
         .Where(x => lst.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList()
         .ForEach(item => myString = myString.Replace(item, string.Format("$${0}$$", item)));
```

Comment: this seems very expensive

Comment: The `contains` check doesn't achieve much.

Comment: Farhad has gave it to you for free

Comment: Typo in the `Where()`? `str.Contains(str)` will always be true... (actually, as with the `contains()` check, the `Where()` is unnecessary).

Comment: how can I make this a non case-sensitive (either one of the answers)?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, the code with the case-insensitive does not work, can you tell why?

Comment: @Bergkamp I have cretaed a demo console app and it works. Could you check that after cleaning and rebuilding your application?